# Deno official server example doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

when I go to: https://deno.land/, and I try the sample:

```
    import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.74.0/http/server.ts";
const s = serve({ port: 8000 });
console.log("http://localhost:8000/");
for await (const req of s) {
  req.respond({ body: "Hello World\n" });
}
```

on a simple index.ts, and run it on the terminal: deno index.ts
it simply does not work. I get errors saying that the link on the import should not end with .ts, and the "for-await-of" can only be called when its async, and it just seems so unusual that the code sample given by the company it-self has bugs. I have tried other samples that they give but they all end up with the same error. I just want to see how to make deno servers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably you ran this code with another program (e.g. Node.js)

Comment: copied the code and ran it like you said with `deno index.ts`, but only got this message: `error: Found argument 'index.ts' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context` plus some usage guidance, nothing about import and .ts endings and also nothing about "for-await-off". Can't reproduce these errors. Some more details hwat you did and what exactly happened would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong command to run the code.  Save it in a file as index.ts, which I think you've done, and then run it with `deno run --allow-net index.ts`.  It should respond http://localhost:8000/ in the console.  Now put localhost:8000 in the address bar of a browser, and the browser should display 'Hello World'.